# display parent category and sub category and sub sub category name from product collection

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I am try to write product categories name into csv file. My requirement is have three column in csv "parent category name" and "subcategory name" "subsub category name"

So i get product collection and got a categories ids by below code.

```
$products = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->getCollection();

foreach ($products as $product) {
   $catIds = $product->getCategoryIds();
}
```

Example tree structure: CategoryName -- (Category Id)

```
Main Category --(3) 
   Sub_Cat_1 (4)  
      SubSub_Cat_1 (6)
      SubSub_Cat_2 (7)
      SubSub_Cat_3 (8)

    Sub_Cat_2(5)
      SubSub_Cat_4 (9)
      SubSub_Cat_5 (10)
```

So i got the $catIds = array(3,4,5,6,7) but i want name with relation.

So i want below output in CSV file.

```
Parent_Cat       |   Sub_Cat            |   SubSub_Cat
Main Category    | Sub_Cat_1,Sub_Cat_2  | SubSub_Cat_1,SubSub_Cat_2
```

I have tried lot of methods but no luck.

So please kindly help in advance to achieve.

Thanks,

Comment: Please any one give me solution to this.

Answer (score 1):

You can have an array containing all the categories on their specific level (each key will represent a level) like this:

```
    $categoriesLevels = array();
    $categoryModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
    $tree = $categoryModel->getTreeModel();
    $tree->load();
    $catIds = $tree->getCollection()->getAllIds();
    foreach ($catIds as $catId){
        $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($catId);
        $catLevel = $category->getLevel();
        if (!isset($categoriesLevels[$catLevel])) {
            $categoriesLevels[$catLevel] = array();
        }
        $categoriesLevels[$catLevel] = array_merge($categoriesLevels[$catLevel],array($category->getName()));
    }
    $categoriesLevels = array_filter($categoriesLevels);
```

So $categoriesLevels[0] will contain the name of the Root Catalog, $categoriesLevels[1] will contain the name of the Default Category, $categoriesLevels[2] will contain the name of all the Subcategories, $categoriesLevels[3] will contain the name of all the SubSubcategories, etc.

*edit*

If you only want the categories for a specific product, just change the way the `$catIds` are obtained:

```
    $categoriesLevels = array();
    $catIds = $product->getCategoryIds();
    foreach ($catIds as $catId){
        $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($catId);
        $catLevel = $category->getLevel();
        if (!isset($categoriesLevels[$catLevel])) {
            $categoriesLevels[$catLevel] = array();
        }
        $categoriesLevels[$catLevel] = array_merge($categoriesLevels[$catLevel], array($category->getName()));
    }
    $categoriesLevels = array_filter($categoriesLevels);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Bogdam Tomi.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i find the solution so please check this for my answer.

```
$products = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->getCollection();
$products->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1);
$products->addAttributeToSelect('*');

$cats = $product->getCategoryIds();
$cat_lel_one = array();
$cat_lel_two = array();
$cat_lel_third = array();
   foreach ($cats as $category_id) {
      $_cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())->load($category_id);

      $cat_info = $_cat->getData();
      if($cat_info['level'] == 1){
         $cat_lel_one[] = $_cat->getName();
      }
      if($cat_info['level'] == 2){
         $cat_lel_two[] = $_cat->getName();
      }
      if($cat_info['level'] == 3){
         $cat_lel_third[] = $_cat->getName();
      }
   }
```

> My first level of categories in $cat_lel_one variable. My Second level
>   of categories in $cat_lel_two variable. My third level of categories
>   in $cat_lel_third variable.